# Managing Clicks On overlapping FloatingActionButton and ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view, floating-action-button

I am creating a view like this[image]

I have used constraint layout for setting progressbar on top of floating action button.

Like this

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/playBarView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/containerLayout">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_prev" />

                <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/musicButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:elevation="2dp"
                    app:fabCustomSize="60dp"
                    app:maxImageSize="40dp"
                    app:rippleColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_next" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/playProgress"
                style="?android:progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:progress="70"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Problem is that when I click on it, only progress bar click is triggered which makes sense because progress bar is on top of FAB.

I want the ripple click effect applied on the FAB when I click on it.

Is there any way that I can disable the click on the progress bar and only set FAB clickable ?

Comment: `progressBar.setEnabled(false)`. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, it disabled the click on the progressbar but also doesn't detect click of FAB

Answer (score 0):

Disabling clicks should do the trick.
Add `android:clickable="false"` to progressbar xml or `progressBar.setClickable(false);` in code.
Also, you can set touch listener to prevent touches from being blocked:
`progressBar.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> false);`

Comment: Did not work, It disables the progress bar click, but I want to enable the f=FloatingActionButton  click as well

Comment: Please, attach an xml snippet of these elements and how overlapping is done